# AWS Cognito send empty codeParameter to custom_email_sender lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, incognito-mode

I try to configure my aws `cognito` service to send mails through a custom `lambda`, but the `codeParameter` parameter from the event is empty. This is a part of the event I receive :

```
"triggerSource": "CustomEmailSender_SignUp",
"request": {
    "userAttributes": {
        "cognito:email_alias": "*****@gmail.com",
        "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
        "email": "****@gmail.com",
        "email_verified": "false",
        "sub": "*******"
    },
    "codeParameter": "",
    "usernameParameter": "",
    "clientMetadata": null
},
```

The user pool seems to be properly configured since the lambda is correctly called with the correct event, but maybe I've done something wrong since the documentation is ... quite not intuitive on this part.

If you have any idea I'd love to hear from you !

Edit 1:
This is how cognito is created in my terraform file :

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "cognitoKMSKey" {
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.this.account_id}:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "${data.aws_caller_identity.this.arn}"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "cognitoUsersPool" {
  name                     = "cognitoUsersPool"
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]
  username_attributes      = ["email"]

  lambda_config {
    custom_email_sender {
      lambda_arn     = aws_lambda_function.lambdaConfirmUser.arn
      lambda_version = "V1_0"
    }
    kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.cognitoKMSKey.arn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`codeParameter` is only used when Cognito needs you to send a cognito code to the user for use with cognito. This does not have happen with `CustomEmailSender_SignUp` it does happen with `CustomMessage_SignUp` as detailed by [CustomMessage handler docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javascript-cognito-lambda-trigger-custom-message-sign-up.js.html).

So ignore the `codeParameter`.

For the `CustomEmailSender` handlers, the relevant parameters are `trigger.request.code` not `codeParameter`. (As can be seen in the [CustomEmailSender documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html))

The `trigger.request.code` will only be set if you have configured a secret in cognito. Since it isn't populated, Cognito doesn't have access to use the KMS key. Cgonito says the requirement is to specify this configuration **Including the KMS keyId**:

```sh
--lambda-config
  "CustomEmailSender={LambdaVersion=V1_0,LambdaArn=lambda-arn}, KMSKeyID=key-id"
```

You can see this working or not working by checking the CloudTrail for KMS, you should see an attempt by Cognito to use your KMS and result, i.e. whether or not it was successful. If isn't successful, you know this is the problem, and work to solve that. When it is successful, the `trigger.request.code` property will be correctly populated.

**Update**: In the case that KMS is working correctly, logging the request to Lambda as close to invocation as possible is critical. For instance if you are mapping in `Go` to `events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage` then you will lose the important `trigger.request.code` value. To validate the request data, log the `trigger` as part of the lambda function invocation, you should see the `trigger.request.code` there. It does actually seem that part of the problem was due to the fact that the necessary interface was not being used and needed to be added to the AWS-Lambda-Go SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/pull/419/files

Comment: Ok, then I guess I set the wrong event type as a receiver for my golang lambda, there is no `trigger.request.code`. Do you have any idea in Golang what is the correct event to receive ? ATM I have set this one : `events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage`. But maybe something is missing from go sdk like this issue seems to say : https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/issues/370

Comment: 100% yes, if you map to the `events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage` then you definitely will lose the property you care about.